# how to render amd module in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, requirejs, amd

I have an Amd module from an external link and I want to load that in ReactJs project which has been created with CRA. I don't know what to do. I've searched a lot but no answer I found.

I'm using ReactJs with CRA.

this is my Amd module for example:

````
define(["exports", "react", "@emotion/css"], function (_exports, _react, _css) {
  "use strict";

  Object.defineProperty(_exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
  });
  _exports.Props = _exports.Component = void 0;
  _react = _interopRequireDefault(_react);

  var _templateObject;

  function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { "default": obj }; }

  function _taggedTemplateLiteral(strings, raw) { if (!raw) { raw = strings.slice(0); } return Object.freeze(Object.defineProperties(strings, { raw: { value: Object.freeze(raw) } })); }

  var Props = [];
  _exports.Props = Props;

  var Component = function Component(props) {
    return /*#__PURE__*/_react["default"].createElement("div", null, /*#__PURE__*/_react["default"].createElement("div", {
      className: (0, _css.css)(_templateObject || (_templateObject = _taggedTemplateLiteral(["\n          padding: 0 16px;\n          max-width: 1200px;\n          margin: 0 auto;\n        "])))
    }, props.children));
  };

  _exports.Component = Component;
});```
````